# Math subject GRE test 9768 Q.26

Tags: maxima-minima, gre-exam

What is the fastest way to solve this question?

I checked and I found that the derivative exists at $x = 1$.

> [image]

Comment: Sketch the graph of $f$

Comment: This is the fastest way.... how? the question must take only 2.5 minutes in the exam @Nil

Comment: @MundronSchmidt: $ -x^2+4x-2=-(x-2)^2+2$

Comment: Drawing this graph should not take anywhere near 2.5 minutes.  You only need a few points to see what is happening, maybe $-1,0,1,2$, if you recognize the inverted parabolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can just compute $f$ at $0,1,2$ getting $-2,1,-2$ so clearly A and C are wrong.  Because the quadratic term is negative the function will go to $-\infty$ as $x$ gets large in either direction, so it will have some absolute maximum, and D is wrong.  You can compute the derivative at $0,2$ and find it is nonzero to rule out $E$.  The answer is B.  There is no derivative at B because above $1$ is is $-2$ and below $1$ it is $+2$.  Since the derivative fails to exist it is a candidate for a local maximum, which it is.  It is also the global maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Both components are concave parabolas, with vertices respectively in $x=2$ and $x=0$. So the first component is increasing for $x<1$ and the second component is decreasing for $x \ge 1$. The function is continuous at $x=1$. Therefore (B) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The functions agree at $1$ so $f$ is continuous. Verify that $f'(x) > 0$ to the left of $1,$ and $f'(x) <0$ to the right of $1.$ It follows that $f$ has an absolute max at $1.$